# How to use image_url helper in GraphQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, graphql

In the Action View the helper image_url returns this:

```
http://localhost:3010/assets/no-image-hash.jpg
```

For GraphQL in the config/initializers directory I put the following file:

```
module GraphQL
  module Define
    class DefinedObjectProxy
      include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper
      include ImagesHelper
    end
  end
end
```

But it didn't help.

Inside the GraphQL type, the field returns the following:

```
"image": "/images/no-image.jpg",
```

And it should be this:

```
http://localhost:3010/assets/no-image-hash.jpg
```

Why doesn't it work and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When using `image_url` outside the standard request context you will need to access it with `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path("example.png")` to get the image hash.

Further discussion/ other solutions here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10051

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `image_url()`. [Have a glimpse at the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html):

> Computes the full URL to an image asset. This will use image_path internally, so most of their behaviors will be the same. Since image_url is based on asset_url method you can set :host options. If :host options is set, it overwrites global config.action_controller.asset_host setting.
>
> image_url "edit.png", host: "http://stage.example.com" # => http://stage.example.com/assets/edit.png

Comment: It's not just a lack of host. There is no hash. The path after the host is incorrect. This method doesn't work correctly.

Comment: What is `ImagesHelper` module doing?

Comment: is it Spina by any chance?

Comment: There's a simple check - `present?`.